# Python | Arbitrary arguments

Tags: python

I have to take arbitrary arguments of lists in a function

This code works fine

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6,7]

def joiner(m,n):
    o = []
    return m+n+o

print joiner(a,b)
```

but when I change the code to arbitrary arguments and it is not working

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[5,6,7]

def joiner(*m):
    o = []
    return m+o

print joiner(a,b)
```

What could be the reason for this

Comment: Have you tried your code? The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: the o is doing nothing ... just so you know

Answer (score 3):

`m` is a tuple containing the two (or more, or less) lists. You need to loop through `m` to get a general version of your function

```
def joiner(*m):
    o = []
    for item in m:
        o += item
    return o
```

You can do this in a one liner, but I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The star `*` syntax in a function or method signature packs positional arguments into a `tuple` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/2069350) for lots of details). Your second function receives a single argument, called `m`, that looks (for example) like this:

```
([1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7])
```

If you want to then access each member of that tuple (each argument) individually, you must do that explicitly--Python can't magically intuit that you want to add all your arguments together.

```
def joiner(*args):
    o = []
    for arg in args: # Iterate over each argument your function received.
        o += arg   # or better, o.extend(arg)
    return o
```

---

There are also tools that already exist to do this for you: specifically, [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
def joiner(*m):
    return list(itertools.chain(*m))
```

Of course at that point (as others have mentioned), you might as well not write the `joiner` function at all, since it's just a few extra steps under the hood to wrap an `itertools.chain` call.

...Actually, any time you do pretty much *anything* with one or more iterables, you should go look at the `itertools` module and see if someone has already implemented it for you. :-)

Comment: arg ... so close to a +1 .. get rid of the sum comment ... while true that is junky code, and a bad habit to teach or encourage(less clear and much much much slower than other methods)

Comment: Agreed 100% with Joran. The only reason `sum` works in this case is that the author of the function couldn't think of a good way to make it _not_ work with arbitrary iterables (because `Iterable` didn't exist yet). The right way to write this is with `chain`, as in his answer, or by doing it explicitly.

Comment: The problem with sum here, is that it has quadratic performance for pretty much anything that's not numbers.

Comment: there now you get my +1 :P

Comment: Yes, yes, pardon my impropriety, everybody :-p The `sum` was just a placeholder while I made sure I remembered how `itertools.chain` worked.

Comment: @gnibbler: The real problem with `sum` is that it's misleading. People have proposed "fixes" numerous times to make it use `+=` instead of `+`, which would give it amortized linear or log-linear performance with all mutable iterables (and with strings, for a different reason), but the idea is always rejected because `sum` is for summing numbers, and `chain` is for chaining iterables.

Answer (score 2):

my contribution to the flurry of answers that are all correct :P

```
import itertools

def joiner(*m):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(m)
```

Comment: This is good if you don't actually need a list. But you could just say `joiner = itertools.chain` :)

Comment: :P I know ... but meh I figured Id keep it in a method like he has it

Comment: @gnibbler: If you actually need a list, `return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(m))`.

Comment: Or, alternatively, there's [this pattern](http://pastebin.com/Q9vas8bT) to get back a <whatever you passed in>, so joining three `deque`s together returns a `deque`. (Of course joining two `deque`s, a `list`, and a `tuple` also returns a `deque`… but in that case, you're asking for it…)